# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error when I try to use insertTimeRange

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to merge several videos using AVFoundation, but I keep getting an error and I cannot figure out why I am getting it. I have tried several solutions that I have found on SO but I have yet to successfully resolve the issue. I keep getting the error message on both of the lines with "insertTimeRange". I am sure it is probably a simple fix but I cannot figure it out.

**Error Message:**

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
if firstAsset != nil && secondAsset != nil && thirdAsset != nil {
           
     var mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
     
     let track1to2Time = CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)
     let totalTime = CMTimeAdd(track1to2Time, thirdAsset.duration)
     
     var firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
     firstTrack!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: firstAsset.duration), 
          ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero, error: nil)
     
     var secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video, preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
     secondTrack!.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: secondAsset.duration), 
          ofTrack: secondAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack, atTime: firstAsset.duration, error: nil)

  //.....
}
```

Comment: The Swift version of insertTime throws instead of returning an error. Remove the parameter error: and use try instead.

Comment: @Dale You got there just before me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I eventually came up with....

```
let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        
        guard
            let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(
                withMediaType: .video,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        else { return }
        
        do {
            try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(
                CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: firstAsset.duration),
                of: firstAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                at: .zero)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load first track")
            return
        }
        
        guard
            let secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(
                withMediaType: .video,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        else { return }
        
        do {
            try secondTrack.insertTimeRange(
                CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: secondAsset.duration),
                of: secondAsset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0],
                at: firstAsset.duration)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to load second track")
            return
        }
```